# read and return text file with def function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

i want to input the file name in this case books.txt and get the lines but i cant get it work, i have the files in the same directory but when i run this nothing happens, any way to fix this? or to call that function in another .py file

```
books.txt

7,1,2,3,4,3
2,6,1,3,1
```

```
file_name = input("type the file name: ")
def read_txt(file_name)
    file = open(file_name, "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    return lines

read_txt(file_name)
```

but this return nothing and i dont know what to do :(

Comment: Accepting the file name as a command-line argument is almost always a better design than requiring interactive prompting. That way, the user can use the shell's history, wildcard, tab completion etc and loop over files etc much more easily. Look at `sys.argv` for simply getting a list of strings as command-line arguments, and `argparse` for more advanced argument handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this line to the end, so it actually prints out the values:

```
print(read_txt(file_name))
```

So the full code would be (I also changed some code as the OP said what to change):

```
file_name = input("type the file name: ")
def read_txt(file_name):
    file = open(file_name, "r")
    lines = [x for i in file.readlines() for x in list(map(int, i.strip().split(',')))]
    file.close()
    return lines
print(read_txt(file_name))
```

Output:

```
[7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3 2, 6, 1, 3, 1]
```

Comment: thanks, i get this ['7,1,2,3,4,3\n', '2,6,1,3,1'] how i can print like this
7,1,2,3,4,3
2,6,1,3,1  #separated lines

Comment: @Deepssz I edited my answer, you can check it out :-)